# Subtract two times within the same list to find duration

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I'm working on a script that reads a log file and outputs all of the logs that contain 'Send' with the start and end times associated. my script output has the logs looking like this:

```
['Send', '2020-02-02T08:35:12.242Z', '2020-02-02T08:45:10.355Z']
['Send', '2020-02-02T08:52:23.692Z', '2020-02-02T08:58:43.118Z']
```

I'm trying to do two things. I'm trying to extract the timestamps to take the difference and get the duration of each 'send' in a regular H:M:S format. I've tried looking at `datetime` documentation and `strftime` to convert the time values but I can't figure out how to get the two times out of the outputted lists.

I'm then trying to export a csv file where the format looks like:

```
Status, Start, End, Duration
Send, 2020-02-02T08:35:12.242Z, 2020-02-02T08:45:10.355Z, 09:58.113
Send, 2020-02-02T08:52:23.692Z, 2020-02-02T08:58:43.118Z, 06:19.426
```

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: @Chris I’m not, I’m very new to coding. I’m assuming I can achieve this by using pandas?

Comment: I would recommend using it; although it is not the only way to do so.

Comment: If you are using `Python 2.7` as tagged, you should upgrade to `Python 3` as 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? What does _I can’t figure out how to get the two times out of the outputted lists_ mean, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) module to convert the times to datetimes using [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), then take the difference between these datetimes. Once you have this you can write the results to an output file using [`csv.writer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

**Demo:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from csv import writer

data = [
    ["Send", "2020-02-02T08:35:12.242Z", "2020-02-02T08:45:10.355Z"],
    ["Send", "2020-02-02T08:52:23.692Z", "2020-02-02T08:58:43.118Z"],
]

with open("result.csv", mode="w", newline='') as csv_out:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_out)
    csv_writer.writerow(["Status", "Start", "End", "Duration"])

    for send, t1, t2 in data:
        d1 = datetime.strptime(t1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
        d2 = datetime.strptime(t2, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
        csv_writer.writerow([send, t1, t2, d2 - d1])
```

**result.csv**

```
Status,Start,End,Duration
Send,2020-02-02T08:35:12.242Z,2020-02-02T08:45:10.355Z,0:09:58.113000
Send,2020-02-02T08:52:23.692Z,2020-02-02T08:58:43.118Z,0:06:19.426000
```

**Note:** This obviously doesn't match the exact result you want, but I'll leave the rest for you to figure out :)